# How to animate view with accelerometer?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-sensors

I have a following problem: imagine a frame in the center of a screen like in most of photo apps. When you move or tilt your device the frame should leave a trail like on a picture below (not very good example, but I can't find a better one):

[image: cursor with trail]

In the current implementation I get accelerometer data greater than certain threshold and animate trail on Canvas posting Runnable to Handler. Does this implementation have pitfalls? Or are there any better ways to implement such functionality?

Comment: It is better with ROTATION_VECTOR Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

Comment: @arjun.9990 May be, but it doesn't help with fast device movement

Comment: If you want a better answer you should ask a better question. Show us code, explain the exact problem you are having and what you tried so far to fix it. General question like is this implementation better than the other implementation are not what Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: @XaverKapeller may be it's not the best question, but I don't need code or implementation I need starting point, because I think that problem was solved many times. Well, and I don't know place better than Stack Overflow to ask such questions. If you think that my question is in the wrong place just flag it.

Comment: @Vang are you asking what's the best way to handle accelerometer data, or to animate it?

Comment: I'm asking about best way to animate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to implement these two functionalities, to get a better overall experience on your motion:

1. Linear averaging

You have a class that monitors the accelerometer data every *t* time. Instead of directly having the measurement affect your object, use an average over *n*t* times. So each new measurement is added to the rolling average, and one bad measurement has less effect on your behaviour.

2. Acceleration

Implementing acceleration allows for your user to get a better accelerometer to movement experience. [This](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/) is a great article regarding how to implement motion equations into your movements.

Afterwards, the exact implementation that you use will be dependant on a lot of things, namely your assets and usage of these assets. Posting a Runnable to a Handler is not, inherently, bad IPC, yet we cannot tell you more without seeing some of your code.